# Why can't I access class Meta as a attribute of Django Model Class?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Python I can define:

```
class Person(object):
   name = "Easwar"
   age = 35
   sex = "male"

   class Occupation:
      name = "my_job"
```

I can then access it

```
>> p = Person()
>> p.Occupation.name
>> # prints "my_job"
```

However in Django, if I have a model defined with Class Meta inside I cannot do this

```
>>> m = SomeDjangoModel()
>>> m.Meta
>>> # prints AttributeError!
```

Why is this ? 
How is Django's inner Meta class different from a regular Python class ?

I did research this and didnt come up with anything similar asked here. 
Please excuse me if I have missed it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The Meta attribute is changed by metaclass.

Try:

```
SomeDjangoModel._meta
```

Comment: Thanks, I do it that way in my code, but is not using 'underscore prefixed' variables discouraged ?  I was just wondering why this has been made so opaque in Django

Comment: I agree, but it is widely used in Django code (e.g. _meta.get_field_by_name)

Comment: @dreaswar underscore-prefixed variables are meant to be (by convention) private variables in Python

Comment: @Don do i have to access it using the class name? Is there a way to access it say in a mixin that comes before in MRO?

I am trying to access it in the mixin using self._meta or self.Meta but either won't work

Answer (score 4):

A `Meta` attribute defined on a class is a bespoke pattern for associating and containing additional data that is going to be introspected by the class' metaclass upon type creation.

You can review the [`ModelBase`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L58) metaclass and see how it uses the `Meta` attribute to configure the resulting model class that's being constructed.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that now. It does create some magic behind the scenes that you dont expect when you define the Model. You would expect the inner Meta class and its attributes to be available. I am relative noob in Python and not a professional programmer, but I would venture to say this is against Python's principle of being explicit. Lot of magic :)

Comment: It would appear so, but you must understand that this design is usually utilized in an internal API where the metadata attributes and their discrete values may be transformed to modify the resulting class in ways where it may not make sense to continue relying either on the values or the access path of the attributes. What it does quite elegantly accomplish is that it makes it impossible to rely on a `Meta` attribute that's optional, including the metadata contained therein, but on a guaranteed `_meta` attribute with preconfigured defaults.

Comment: Thanks, I was just doing some work with _meta and all the attributes and methods it bundles. I can now appreciate what you meant by saying it has been elegantly accomplished. Makes the magic worth it !

Comment: What is this pattern called? Have observed the same pattern in couple of other packages (like pydantic) and wanted to implement it in one of my projects.